# Forward traffic with iptables without exposing real IP/Port

Tags: iptables, nat, dnat

I want to forward traffic with iptables without showing a different ip/port to sending host.

My application listens on host x.x.15.42, port 23555 using TCP. The client will be connecting to x.x.15.42:5555. I want the connection to be forwarded to port 23555 without exposing that port to the client.

I already tried using DNAT:

`iptables -t nat -A PREROUTING -p tcp --dport 5555 -j DNAT --to-destination x.x.15.42:23555`

But to the client it will show that they're connecting to port 23555.

I also tried using REDIRECT, but for some reason that doesn't work at all. The client can't connect.

`iptables -t nat -A PREROUTING -p tcp --dport 5555 -d x.x.15.42 -j REDIRECT --to-port 23555`

How do I forward this traffic while making it look like the application is listening on port 5555?

Comment: What exactly is the server and client software?

Comment: @TeroKilkanen It's an emulator for an old game.

Comment: This rule does what you want for the first packet, but the server is likely telling the address where client should connect afterwards.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So the first firewall rule I used works:

```
iptables -t nat -A PREROUTING -p tcp --dport 5555 -j DNAT --to-destination x.x.15.42:23555
```

The only problem was indeed that the server was telling the client to connect to port 23555 instead of port 5555 like I wanted. Changing that on the server part fixes the issue.

Answer (score 0):

I'm only a dabbler in iptables, so could you try this:

```
iptables -A PREROUTING -t nat -i eth0 -p tcp --dport 5555 -j DNAT --to x.x.15.42:23555
iptables -A FORWARD -p tcp -d x.x.15.42 --dport 23555 -j ACCEPT
```

Both lines are needed (I think it's the lack of the FORWARD option that's causing this), although not sure if the interface option `-i eth0` is necessary

[Source reference](https://www.systutorials.com/port-forwarding-using-iptables/)

Comment: I tried this. On the first connection it shows port 5555, but after that it will change to port 23555.

I believe this might be caused by the application sending the real port to the client during the communication.

I'm going to try this with a different application like httpd to see if the firewall NAT rules correctly apply on it.